# PHP / Regex: Check if string was copy pasted

Tags: php, regex, string, validation

I am trying to write a validation function for strings where I want to check if the string is a copy+paste work.

Background:

We have a CMS where the user can enter description texts with a minimum of - for example - 200 Chars. A lot of user write too short texts and get the "you have to use more then 200 letters" error message.
To avoid this, they copy paste the text or some dummy strings like "AAAAA" to reach the limit.

I am looking now for an function / methode / regex to detect such copy+paste strings and prevent them by showing a message.

I know that there is no 100% solution to prevent dummy texts, but we want to reduce it a little bit. Any ideas?

Comment: You would probably have to do it via JavaScript somehow.

Comment: You better allow shorter texts.

Comment: Personally, I'd not worry about it. If people want to game the system, there's always a way. They could simply start typing "123456...". And what about if repetition is a stylistic choice? Either way, what you're looking for is the longest common substring. I'd recommend you change your question to this effect or google based on it. And BTW, this is not a trivial problem, probably not worth investing too much time in for the use case you cite.

Comment: You're going to need a complicated heuristic to even come close to solving this issue.  Off hand, you could check to see wether the same character appears a certain number of times in a row (something like `/(.)\1{N,}/`), but that's really only going to get you so far.  I suggest trusting your users, or you're going to sink a lot of time into this project.

Comment: To do this properly you'd need linguistic processing of human language for significance, best done by humans. Anything less is going to generate more false positives, angry users and support hassles than it will stop poor descriptions. Forcing the user to do what they don't want usually doesn't work and you get the behavior you have. Consider either just letting it slide. Or eliminate the minimum description requirement. Or break up the large description into a bunch of shorter, easier to answer questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not going to be a fast, reliable, undefeatable solution. But I can think of a compromise:

```
preg_match('/(.{1,4})\1{3,}/', $subject)
```

would return `True` for strings that contain repeated sequences of one to four characters (when they're repeated at least three times).

So it would match on strings like

```
AAAAAAA
asdasdasdasd
foo bar baz glglglglglglglgl
```

It would not detect longer repetitions like

```
asdfgasdfgasdfgasdfg
```

but the complexitly of the regex will grow exponentially if you try to match longer repeats, so I think four characters are a workable compromise.

Alternatively, you might want to anchor the repeats to the end of the string (which is where most people would put the filler):

```
preg_match('/(.+)\1{3,}$/', $subject)
```

but of course, then a string like

```
LOL OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!.
```

would not be detected. Your choice :)

Comment: Thank you! That was a good hint to find the solution for my specific problem.